# gps mobile phones connectivity

Tags: gps

all the sets will not have inbuilt gps connectivity....for example mine is sony Ericsson z550i in this i dont have  inbuilt gps service. suppose i want to use gps service in such sets what i should do? please Suggest some alternatives...

And also suggest is it mandatory to have a gprs connection for my handset if i want to avail gps service?

Answer (score 1):

GPS does not require any cellular connection like GPRS, it relies purely on a GPS antenna on the phone picking signals from orbiting GPS satellites.

If a phone doesn't have a GPS system, then there might be other APIs available to obtain an approximate position from cell tower information, but generally speaking I think you're out of luck.